# How to change calendar color with Google Calendar API v3?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I've got this code snippet, which edits the calendar summary with google calendar API v3:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar = mService.calendars().get(CalendarActivity.this.editid).execute();
calendar.setSummary(CalendarActivity.this.title);
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar updatedCalendar = mService.calendars().update(calendar.getId(), calendar).execute();
```

But how to change the color of calendar?

There is no `setColorId()` method. Don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In Calendar API, you can set the color when you're talking about events when you use [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) using the `colorId` property. However, looking at [Calendar.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) docs, there's no method to set the color for calendars, only for events.

Comment: So there is no possibility to change the calendar color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarListEntry;

// ...

// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Retrieve the calendar list entry
CalendarListEntry calendarListEntry = service.calendarList().get("calendarId").execute();

// Make a change
calendarListEntry.setColorId("0");

// Update the altered entry
CalendarListEntry updatedCalendarListEntry =
    service.calendarList().update(calendarListEntry.getId(), calendarListEntry).execute();

System.out.println(updatedCalendarListEntry.getEtag());
```

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/update